# Best apache mods for mage 2.4.4

Tags: magento2.4.4, apache

so other than the baseline required apache mods for magento 2.4.4 (as per https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/prereq/apache.html). What other mods do you think should be enabled in apache to improve performance?

For example, I noticed that I don't have mod_cache enabled, should I?
Or will that break magento?

Thanks for your advice in advance :)